# mstest.exe is absent in VS2013 installation folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, mstest

Due to Microsoft's official cite it must be located at

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\
```

Didn't find such topics in google or stackOverflow...

In the same time I can run Unit tests from VS, but I need to run them from cmd... Have someone some ideas why its absent and how to fix this?

for "MSTest" command "Developer Command Prompt for VS2013" returns me error:

```
'MSTest' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Perhap's already done but... nothing found when doing a simple file search in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\ ?

Comment: Do you have `vstest.console.exe`? For me it's in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe`. According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSTest) it's the recommended tool now

Comment: Emmanuel Istace: yeah, nothing was found. Only file
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\*Microsoft.VisualStudio.MSTest.TestWindow.dll*

Comment: Blorgbeard: "vstest.console.exe" -- yeah, I have it

Comment: Ah good, well you could use that instead of mstest: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is at

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE

in my installation. Could you take a look at there.

**Edit:**
As it is express edition you should download and install Agents for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40750

Comment: I've got it there. What edition of VS did you install?

Comment: http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs.aspx in here says some versions don't have Manual Testing option. Maybe it could be related to this.

Comment: Express may well not have mstest included.

Comment: @Andrew You can check my improved answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  @Mahmut Ali ÖZKURAN

Answer (score 0):

Blorgbeard opened my eyes =)
For my needs I can use "vstest.console.exe" or "TCM.exe".

Even if I didnt find the reason why is absent mstest.exe in my installation folder, its resolves my problem.

Thanks a lot, Blorgbeard and all of you!